# How to smoothly migrate the quartz tables to different sql database?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

I’m using quartz.net library in my C# application and using sql server for quartz related tables. My application is a multi-tenant application and for each tenant there is a separate databases. Each database has its own quartz tables.

now I am planning to have a single database. I want to have only one database. I have only one concern that there are many jobs which are already scheduled from long time in these databases. So how can I move to a single database without any loss of scheduled jobs/triggers?

Will it work if I copy all the quartz tables records to this new quartz database respective tables?

quartz.net version: 3.5.0

I had posted the same question on [GitHub](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/discussions/2233) as well, but didn’t get response. So I’m posting here as well for the better reach.